# Film or TV show about a Magic Marble

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify a fantasy story that was either a movie (theatrical or made for TV) or show I saw as a young child. In it, there is a Magic Marble that can work magic and has a will of its own, but when held by someone, it has to obey them. I remember one key scene very vividly:

The marble has fallen into the hands of a child who is the villain after it had been in possession of a child who is the protagonist. The villain holds the marble and makes himself all-powerful. He is sitting on a throne or standing at the top of stone steps somewhere outdoors during the daytime. He is gloating over the protagonist, who has been apprehended by the soldiers he wished for. As he gloats, he begins tossing the marble up into the air and catching it. Thinking fast, the protagonist waits until the marble is in the air (i.e., not in the villain's possession) and shouts: "Magic Marble help me!" The villain and all his soldiers disappear, and the protagonist catches the marble as it bounces down the steps. I can recall very few other details, but here they are:

- I seem to recall the entire cast was children.
- I think the actors all had American accents.
- The movie or show was in color.
- I think it was on PBS (New York Metro area Public Broadcasting Service)
- I seem to recall that the scene I described and perhaps the rest of the production was set in China (based on set design and costumes), though all the principle characters I recall were caucasian.
- I saw it some time between 1973 and 1979, though it could easily have been filmed earlier.

Would love it if someone could help me id this story.

Comment: So not *[One Wish Too Many](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4S-FiUYPWo)*?

Comment: Thinking that this might have been a [Zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoom_(1972_TV_series)) Play of the Week. A quick check of the existing ones on YouTube show all children actors and basic sets. If any of the children had striped shirts that would be a stronger indication.

Comment: So far, I've found nothing, but http://filmdope.com/forums/84174-magic-marble-film.html might be useful to others.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Led me to the list of [Children's Film Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Film_Foundation) films which led to [The Glitterball (1977)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Glitterball) which [actually aired on WNET in NYC](https://www.nytimes.com/1979/07/28/archives/television.html). Clip [here on YouTube](https://youtu.be/m-3sGWAD2aI)

Comment: @MorrisonChang: I saw that one, but I didn't see any matching details in the plot.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Good point. Found the plot details - yeah I'm going to have to agree. Adults and a department store doesn't fit.

Comment: No, not One Wish Too Many, though that was the only movie I could find through Google before posting here. Also not The Glitterball. Thanks to everyone for trying. Hopefully there'll be someone on here who was older when they saw this and has a better memory of it.